# Django Admin restrict users to be added to more than one group

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I am creating a customised Django Admin and I want to restrict users to be associated to no more than one group. I am using Django 4.1 and Python 3.11

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from typing import Set

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .models import User


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    ordering = ('is_staff', 'is_active', 'email', 'organisation')
    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'organisation', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined')
    fieldsets = (
        ("Personal info", {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'password', 'organisation')}),
        ("Permissions", {'fields': (
            # 'is_active',
            # 'is_staff',
            # 'is_superuser',
            'groups',
            # 'user_permissions'
            )}))

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'classes': ('wide',), 'fields': ('name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'organisation')}),
    )
```

Is there a way to change this in the admin code?

Or it is possible to disable the group widget ("Choose all") on the page? if so which html page is used for groups?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to restrict the number of groups a user can be associated with in Django. One way to do this is to override the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method in your custom `UserAdmin` class and perform the check there, so:

```py
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    # ... other stuff
    # ... other stuff

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.groups.count() > 1:
            self.message_user(request, _('Users can only be associated with one group.'), level=messages.ERROR)
        else:
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```